# Set expires header for specific file or url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few vimeo and youtube videos on my site generating a lot of http requests for the css files.

Specifically to:

```
http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/1.4.28/css/player.core.opt.css
```

and

```
http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflOkLJfy.css
```

I'd like to create expiry headers for these files, but not all my CSS in general. (so ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week" is not what I'm looking for)

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Uh, are those servers (`a.vimeocdn.com` and `s.ytimg.com`) under your control at all?

Comment: No, of course not, I just want to add a request that the users browser cache them. Is that impossible?

Comment: It is possible, if you have control over those servers, or if you have a way to request such a configuration from those who have control over these servers. It is not possible to do it yourself from outside of those servers.